# Google Business Email Will Not Receive Online Web Form Sent Mail

Tags: google, php, email, forms

I use Google to manage my email addresses associated with my domain name. I have written a simple script [here](http://connorbowlan.com/contact.php) to allow people to contact me from my website via the form on the page. It will send to almost any email address except for the ones I've created with Google Business. I have contacted my host in regard for it, and I have contacted Google, but neither have provided working solutions.

I considered setting up dummy emails through cPanel, directing the web form script to them, and then forwarding all the mail to my default email address managed with Google business, but Horde, Squirrel Mail, and other email interface softwares don't seem to include a forwarding feature.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: @JohnConde I was just in the middle of writing an answer to this - the question is more about web hosting than web development. It also has a simple web hosting answer. It would most likely be closed as off-topic if it was posted on SO.

Comment: @JohnConde The same situation would also apply to almost any script/program installed on a website that sends mail - eg. WordPress, etc - if it was sending to the same domain. That would be irrespective of if the person asking the question had developed it or not.

Comment: @TimMalone I'll reopen it and check out your answer. If it fits here I'll keep it here. Otherwise I'll migrate it to [so] and add a comment as to why so they keep it open (this question would not be fit for their site in its current form),.

Comment: @JohnConde No problem, sounds like a good plan!

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem when sending mail from a site on a shared hosting account that has its mail hosted offsite.

What your host needs to do is *disable local mail delivery* for your domain name. Depending on what control panel they offer you, you may even be able to do this yourself. For example, in cPanel (which you might have access to at `http://example.com/cpanel`, where example.com is your domain), you can navigate to 'Remote MX Wizard' under the E-mail heading (it might be named slightly differently depending on the version of cPanel your host uses) and there will be options in here to disable local delivery (the option may also be labelled 'use a remote mail exchanger').

This will be different if your host uses a different control panel. Either way, your host should be able to help you with this. You might need to spell it out, because some hosting level 1 support teams tend to not immediately pick up on solutions to non-straight-forward problems ;)